# how to publish angular 2 typescript library on npm

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack, bundler

I have created a typescript library for angular 2 which facilitates the  to access my backend service.

So far it's a private repo, but I want to upload it as an open source library to github and register it on npm.

I'm not really sure what to do now, since documentation on this subject is not easy to find.

the folder structure looks like this:

```
src
|--sdk.ts // entry point
|--services
   |--auth.ts
   |--database.ts
   |--5 more ts files
|--utils
   |--utils.ts
   |--interfaces.ts
|--tests (8 ..spec.ts files)
```

my entry point (sdk.ts) looks like this

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SelfbitsDatabase } from './services/database';
import { SelfbitsAuth } from './services/auth';
import { SelfbitsAppConfig } from './utils/interfaces';
import { SelfbitsFile } from './services/file';
import { SelfbitsUser } from './services/user';
import { SelfbitsDevice } from './services/device';
import { SelfbitsPush } from './services/push';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class SelfbitsAngular {
    constructor(
        public auth : SelfbitsAuth,
        public database : SelfbitsDatabase,
        public file : SelfbitsFile,
        public user : SelfbitsUser,
        public device: SelfbitsDevice,
        public push : SelfbitsPush
    ){}
}

export const SELFBITS_PROVIDERS:any[] = [
    SelfbitsAngular,
    SelfbitsAuth,
    SelfbitsDatabase,
    SelfbitsFile,
    SelfbitsUser,
    SelfbitsDevice,
    SelfbitsPush
];

@NgModule({
    providers:SELFBITS_PROVIDERS,
    imports:[ HttpModule ]
})

export class SelfbitsAngularModule{
    static initializeApp(config:SelfbitsAppConfig):ModuleWithProviders{
        return {
            ngModule:SelfbitsAngularModule,
            providers:[
                { provide: 'SelfbitsConfig', useValue: config }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the webpack.config.js which doesn't really do what I want...

```
module.exports = {
    entry:'./src/sdk.ts',
    output:{
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename:'selfbitsangular2sdk.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude:'/test/',
                loaders: ['ts-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I'm not sure if webpack is even the right choice..or wether is should be bundled and minified or not. Any hints and tipps are welcome!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular University has a good, step by step, tutorial on publishing an Angular 2 library to npm that addresses your concerns/questions.

You can provide a bundled and unbundled version if you wish, I would always provide an unbundled version though. In my libraries I do not provide a bundled version and leave it up to the consumer to bundle and minify.

http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/

---

## Updated answer

*The following steps will go through the process of creating, testing and publishing an unbundled angular module for consumption by a consumer using a bundler (webpack, angular cli, etc). For a more complete answer which includes bundling, see @OleksiiTrekhleb's answer.*

Publishing an angular 2 library can be intimidating, but when it comes down it it's really no different than publish any other package on NPM. The following information will use the folder structure:

- package root

  - src
  - dist

### 1. Setting up tsconfig.json

As with any typescript library you want to have the `declaration` option set to true in your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions` to ensure our consumers can take advantage of types within our package:

```
"declaration": true
```

In `compilerOptions` we also want to specify our `outDir` to keep transpiled code separate from the source:

```
"outDir": "./dist"
```

We want the `include` option to point to our source folder (note `include` is a sibling in relation to `compilerOptions`):

```
"include": [
  "./src"
]
```

Enable the experimental decorator options under `compilerOptions`:

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true
```

To avoid some errors when transpiling, you will need to enable `skipLibCheck` as well:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

**Result**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ]
}
```

### 2. The Module

This example will use a module with a single component. The component is fairly straight forward:

`./src/helloWorld/helloWorld.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    template: '<div>Hello, world</div>'
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {

}
```

The module should add consumable components to `declarations` and `exports`. We need to add to exports so when consumers import our module, they can use our components as well.

`./src/helloWorld/helloWorld.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './helloWorld.component';

const components: any[] = [
    HelloWorldComponent
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: components,
    exports: components // Don't forget to export!
})
export class HelloWorldModule {

}
```

### 3. The barrel

To simplify importing our modules we use a barrel, which file that exports everything to be consumed by our consumers.

`./src/index.ts`

```
export { HelloWorldModule } from './helloWorld/helloWorld.module';
export { HelloWorldComponent } from './helloWorld/helloWorld.component';
```

### 4. Setting up NPM

**Package.json**

In `package.json`, change the `main` property to point to our transpiled barrel, `./dist/index.js`. Also add the `typings` property to point to our barrels definition file `./dist/index.d.ts`.

Add the property `prepublish` under scripts in your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": "tsc"
}
```

Also note that your angular and related dependencies should be under `peerDependencies` and not `dependencies`

**NPM Ignore**

Create a `.npmignore` file in the root of your package and ignore the `src` folder and any other files you do not want published with your package

```
src/
*.log
```

### 5. Testing

You can easily test your npm packages locally with [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link). In your module package folder, run the command `npm link`.

Then in your test project, run the command `npm link <my package name>`

Now you can import your module and add it to your test projects imports without having to publish.

### 6. Publishing

Your package can now be published with a simple [npm publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish)

Comment: I have had terrible luck with this tutorial and the samples are very out of date.

Comment: Yeah, it's cumbersome. Isn't there ant good clean guide out there.

Comment: https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435

Comment: @clint Simply the tutorial is out of date. The tutorial was publsihed at 27 December 2015. Now its 2018 01 07..
This issue could have been avoided by posting the relevant content of the page here and keeping your answer up to date.

Comment: @clint does this include the templates as well? Don't we need to bundle the module or something?

Answer (score 3):

The publishing process itself is pretty easy:

```
# Login with your existing npm user
npm login

# Bump library version
npm version --patch

# Publish your library
npm publish
```

The hardest part is to correctly prepare the content of your `package.json` and  the folder that will hold you build library (one of the common way to name it is `dist`).

Your `dist` folder should contain files that are ready to be consumed by Angular JIT projects as well as by Angular AOT projects. It is also should contain your library bundle that is ready to be consumed by the browser directly (let's say via SystemJS).

In a result your dist folder should contain the following files:

- **index.umd.js** - UMD bundle that is ready for SystemJS consumption
- **index.umd.min.js** - minified version of the bundle to save user's traffic
- **index.umd.js.map**, **index.umd.min.js.map** - for debugging purpose
- ***.js** — [produced by tsc, remember that ngc is a wrapper] compiled JavaScript representation of the component or service *.ts files of your library.
- ***.d.ts** — [produced by tsc, remember that ngc is a wrapper] declaration files. Since *.ts files with types are being transpiled to *.js files that don’t support typings the TypeScript Compiler needs to put all types information to separate *.d.ts files in order to be able to use those *.js files in TypeScript projects later. By the way, there is a DefinitelyTyped project with a lot of type definitions that have been already contributed for a plenty of JS non-TypeScript libraries.
- ***.metadata.json** — metadata associated with the current component (or NgModule). It is kind of JSON representation of the objects we pass to the @Component, @NgModule decorators. This file contains the information that project’s (not library’s) NGC will need that was in the original library *.ts files but was not included in the *.d.ts files.

In this case your package.json should be notified about your build files via `main`, `module` and `typings` fields:

```
 {
   ...
   "main": "./dist/index.umd.js",
   "module": "./dist/index.js",
   "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
   ...
 }
```

You may find more detailed description of what files should be in `dist` folder and how to compile them in [How to create AOT/JIT compatible Angular 4 library with external SCSS/HTML templates](https://medium.com/@trekhleb/how-to-create-aot-jit-compatible-angular-4-library-with-external-scss-html-templates-9da6e68dac6e) article

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still trying to figure out how to do it:

1. Create your library using @jvandemo's [Angular Lib Yeoman generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)
2. After that you just run: `npm adduser` and `npm publish`

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with/writing a few Angular (2+) libraries and the process of bundling and publishing always had been painful, I found [this tool](https://github.com/aminpaks/typescript-library-bundler) which does all the job and makes the library ready to ship with ES5, ES6 and CommonJS format.

It's very easy to use, you just put one file (entry-file) in your tsconfig and i will crawl to all your files and bundle your Angular library, it inline styles and templates of components as well!

I thought it would be useful for others.

Good luck.